# counting presence/absence based on group

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains abundance data of many species at two locations:

```
        sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
SiteA   0   12  0   0
SiteA   0   3   0   0
SiteA   1   0   0   0
SiteB   0   0   6   0
SiteB   2   1   1   0
SiteB   0   1   0   8
```

I would like to calculate two things:

1. how many species are found at each site. In this dummy example, there are two species at SiteA and four species at SiteB.
2. the mean number of taxa in each row for each site. In this case, 1 for SiteA and 2 for SiteB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using `dplyr` and the `tidyverse` packages for these sorts of summarization questions. More here:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/

```
library(tidyverse)
# First I'd like to reshape into long (aka "tidy") format
df_tidy <- df %>%
  mutate(obs_num = row_number()) %>%  # To keep track of orig row
  gather(sp, count, sp1:sp4)

# First question
df_tidy %>%
  # This gives total counts for all recorded combos of site and species
  count(site, sp, wt = count) %>%
  filter(n > 0) %>%
  count(site)        # Count how many rows (ie species) for each site
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  site     nn
#  <chr> <int>
#1 SiteA     2
#2 SiteB     4


# Second question
df_tidy %>%
  # Count how many observations had counts > 0 for each site
  count(site, obs_num, wt = count > 0) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  summarize(avg_taxa = mean(n))

## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  site  avg_taxa
#  <chr>    <dbl>
#1 SiteA        1
#2 SiteB        2
```

Comment: This is so close but not quite working for me. For the first question, I found that each site had the same number of taxa, which was the same as the total number of taxa in the dataset. I tried this with the dummy data I provided and with my real dataset. Any ideas?

Comment: Perfect! This works now. Thanks so much for following up on it.

Comment: Hi @Jon could you please give me a hand here when you have time? I have a similar question, but instead of counting how many are present/absence, I'd like to filter them/keeping them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64806211/subset-data-based-on-presence-absence-on-unique-samples-and-sample-groups-in-r