# Function for changing size of points in geom_point based on sum of presence absence data

Tags: function, ggplot2

I'm working with a species data in presence/absence format set where samples have been taken multiple times a day over a period of several days.

Here's a dummy version of the data:

```
dummy = structure(list(Sample = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B2"), Species = c("snuffles1", 
"snuffles2", "snuffles3", "snuffles1", "snuffles2", "snuffles3", 
"snuffles1", "snuffles2", "snuffles3", "snuffles1", "snuffles2", 
"snuffles3"), Presence = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), Day = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

```
ggplot(dummy[which(dummy$Presence>0),], aes(x = Day, y = Species, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
  geom_count(aes(size = sum(dummy$Presence)))
```

I would like to plot the data in ggplot where the size of each point is dependent on the sum of the number of observations within that group (i.e if on Day A, snuffles1 was observed 2 times, then the point should be size 2, whereas if on Day B, snuffles1 was observed once, the point would be size 1). I hope this makes sense?  This [counting presence/absence based on group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076416/counting-presence-absence-based-on-group) is similar, but not quite what I need.

My guess is that I have to use some sort of function to count the number of observations for each species, depedent on which variable I'm considering, but I am not smart enough to think of how to do this.

Thanks for any and all advice.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an additional count by group. Then plot this data frame as an extra layer using `geom_point`

I am adding breaks to `scale_size` in order to show only the exiting sizes

```r
library(tidyverse)

count_dum <- dummy %>% group_by(Day, Species) %>% summarise(count = sum(Presence))

ggplot(dummy[which(dummy$Presence > 0), ], aes(x = Day, y = Species, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(data = count_dum, aes(size = count), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_size_continuous(breaks = unique(count_dum$count))
```

[image]